# How to make contour plot in matlab using netcdf data

Tags: python, matlab, netcdf4

I have created a contour plot in python using NetCDF data. What I am plotting is velocity in the x-direction with shape (1, 124, 128, 128) where the dimensions are (time, z, y, x). Where I am getting lost is making my plot work in MATLAB. The code that works in python is,

```
import netCDF4 as NC
from netCDF4 import Dataset as NetCDFFile 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nc = NetCDFFile('XYZ_time_1.nc')
u = nc.variables["u"][:,:,:,:] # Velcity in x direction, size(1, 124, 128, 128), [t,z,y,x]
plt.contourf(u[0,:,:,0]) # time[0], z[:], y[:], x[0]
```

My attempt to translate in MATLAB is below. The size of the array is backward from what python interprets with size (128, 128, 124, 1) with dimensions (x, y, z, time). I am new to MATLAB and unsure how to replicate the code. In MATLAB the time dimension is not included in the size() function. How can you make a contour plot in MATLAB using array slicing that will replicate the results in the above python code?

```
filename = 'XYZ_time_1.nc';
ncdisp(filename);
u = ncread(filename, 'u'); # size(128, 128, 124), time not included?
contour(:,:,1) # (x, y, z)
```

The MATLAB code above will work for the special case below in python. The array indexing is where I begin to get lost. I want to be able to y[:] vs z[:] for a fixed x[index]. How can you arrange the index slice to make this work?

```
print(np.shape(nc.variables["u"][0,0,:,:])) # t[0], z[0], y[:],x[:]
plt.contourf(nc.variables['u'][0,0,:,:])
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to answer my own question using the MATLAB permute function. If you are trying to translate array slicing in python to MATLAB it would like as follows.

```
# In python 
import netCDF4 as NC
from netCDF4 import Dataset as NetCDFFile 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nc = NetCDFFile('XYZ_time_1.nc')
u = nc.variables["u"][:,:,:,:]
plt.contourf(u[0,:,:,0]) # time[0], z[:], y[:], x[0]
```

Translated to MATLAB is

```
% In MATLAB
S = permute(u, [3,2,1]) % rearranges the vector to be [z, y, x] 
contourf(S(:,:,1))
```